# sed - how to capitalize every 3rd word?

Tags: sed

Given:

```
main_east_library
main_west_roof
main_north_roof
minor_south_roof
```

How can I used `sed` (specifically, not `awk`, `tr`, etc.) to create:

```
main_east_Library
main_west_Roof
main_north_Roof
minor_south_Roof
```

Something like:

```
$ echo "main_west_library
main_west_roof
main_north_roof
minor_south_roof" | sed 's_\3_upcase(\3)_'
```

Though that gives:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: Invalid back reference
```

Comment: without awk or tr your sed will fail if you try it on a legacy or just other system. Some of the expressions in the answers are GNU extensions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\u&/3'
```

Would capitalise the third sequence of letters from each line.

To capitalise *every* third sequence of letters in each line:

```
sed -E 's/(([[:alpha:]]+[^[:alpha:]]+){2})([[:alpha:]]+)/\1\u\3/g'
```

To capitalise every third sequence of letters *in the whole input*, with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]+' -v ORS= '
   NR % 3 == 0 {$0=toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)}
   {print $0 RT}'
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/\p{alpha}+/++$n % 3 == 0 ? "\u$&" : "$&"/ge'
```

While the `[[:alpha:]]` character class can be a bit random on some systems (for instance on GNU systems, that includes many numerals with the exclusion of the Arabic ones (0123456789)), Perl's `\p{...}` is based on Unicode character properties. So those `\p{alpha}` will include letters in all alphabets and also non-letter alphabetical characters.

It will not include combining diacritics though which means that words like `Stéphane` would be considered as two separate words.

So you may want instead:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/[\p{alpha}\p{mark}]+/++$n % 3 == 0 ? "\u$&" : "$&"/ge'
```

Though that may end-up including too many.

Also note that contrary to GNU `sed`, Perl's `\u` will correctly transform words like `ﬁddle` (where `ﬁ` is one ligature character) to `Fiddle` (2 characters `F` and `i`).

Answer (score 3):

perl

```
perl -pe 's/(?:.*?_){2}\K./\u$&/'
```

It counts 2 sequences of chars ending with underscore, then uppercases the next char.

Answer (score 2):

Another GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([^[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]])/\1\u\2/2'
```

This assumes that the line always start with a word.